# POST Data is not sent

Tags: php, html

I'm having some weird issues with this code block, it's a little school project, going well so far but the form at the bottom is not returning any post data. the var_dump($_POST); never shows any post data being submitted from this particular form.

I just cannot understand why, been struggling with it for so long.

Here's the code, i couldn't understand to format it on this page, adding 4 indents for every line seemed a bit tedious.

```
<?php session_start();
require_once'user.class.php';
require_once 'posts.class.php';
require_once'comments.class.php';
$posts = new Posts($user->getID(), $db);
$comment = new Comments($user->getID(), $db);

include_once'includes/header.php';
include_once'includes/nav.php';
?>

<h2><br></h2>
<?php
include_once'includes/intro.php';

// CONTENT
$post = $posts->showPost($_GET['id']);
$title = $post['title'];
$content = $post['content'];
$created = $post['timestamp'];

echo  "<section> <article class='blogPost'> <header> " . " <h2>$title</h2> " . "<p> Posted on $created <a href ='#comments'> X comments</a></p></header>" . "<p>$content</p>" . "</article> </section>";

var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['submit_comment']) && isset($_POST['id_comment']))  {
  echo "Kom seg inn i ifen";
  $pid = $_GET['id'];
  $comment->newComment ($db, $user->getID(), $pid, $_POST['id_comment']);
  header ("location: showPost.php?id=$pid");
  exit ();
}
?>

<form name='commentform' action='showPost.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>' method='POST'>
<h3>Post a comment</h3>
<p>
<label for='id_comment'>Comment</label>
<textarea name='id_comment' id='id_comment' required></textarea>
</p>
<p><input style='width: 100%;' type='submit' name='submit_comment' value='Legg til kommentar' /></p>
</form>

<?php
include_once'includes/asidefooter.php';
?>
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: There is a "Code Sample" button in the editor that will automatically indent your code snippet 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like if post is data present, the user is redirected. You will only see the post data at the time the form is submitted, and the redirect will cause another page load and the data won't be present anymore.

Can you see the post data if you comment out the redirect, with:

```
//header ("location: showPost.php?id=$pid");
//exit ();
```

Comment: Indeed, it works when i remove those two lines, not sure why i had them in anyway. but i have an echo in the if statement that never triggered. So im still not sure why the header () was ran. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing a redirect, which is turning the request into a GET. If you're trying to submit to a index.php then don't forget the ending slash.

Comment: i commented out the " header ("location: showPost.php?id=$pid"); "
but why would that go off since it is in a if?